# Postgres query to fetch results between two dates

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, select

This is example:

```
create table test (
id int,
name varchar(6),
start_date date,
end_date date
);


insert into test (id,name, start_date, end_date) values (1,'aaa', '2014-07-01', '2014-07-30');
insert into test (id,name, start_date, end_date) values (2,'bbb', '2014-07-01', '2014-08-30');
insert into test (id,name, start_date, end_date) values (3,'ccc', '2014-08-01', '2014-08-30');
insert into test (id,name, start_date, end_date) values (4,'ddd', '2014-08-16', '2014-08-30');
insert into test (id,name, start_date) values (5,'eee', '2014-07-01');
insert into test (id,name, start_date) values (6,'fff', '2014-08-16');
```

I need write query where result will be:

```
2;"bbb";"2014-07-01";"2014-08-30"
3;"ccc";"2014-08-01";"2014-08-30"
4;"ddd";"2014-08-16";"2014-08-30"
5;"eee";"2014-07-01";""
6;"fff";"2014-08-16";""
```

I've written this:

```
select * from test
where (start_date >= '2014-08-15' and (end_date <= current_Date or end_date is null)) or 
(start_date <= '2014-08-15' and end_date is null) ;
```

But I see only ddd,eee and fff records.

Comment: What did you expect ? Your WHERE clause is working as designed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing (intelligently) that you want any period that overlaps with 2014-08-15 to the present date.  If so, this logic returns what you want:

```
select *
from test
where (start_date >= '2014-08-15' and (end_date <= current_Date or end_date is null)) or 
      (start_date <= '2014-08-15' and (end_date > '2014-08-15' or end_date is null));
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/65243/2) is a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Indeed ^^ You are my hero! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the compare operators, you can actually use PostgreSQL's own detection of date (& time) overlaping. There are actually 2 constructs:

**1)** The SQL compatible [`OVERLAPS` operator](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html):

> `(start1, end1) OVERLAPS (start2, end2)`
>   `(start1, length1) OVERLAPS (start2, length2)`

This one does not handle well an open-ended date-period, but you can use the the special `infinity` date for that.

```
select *
from   test
where  (date '2014-08-15', current_date) overlaps
       (start_date, coalesce(end_date, date 'infinity'));
```

As far as I know, you can't use any index to speed up the query above.

Also:

> Each time period is considered to represent the half-open interval *start* <= *time* < *end*, unless start and end are equal in which case it represents that single time instant.

**2)** Using the [`daterange` type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html):

Ranges can be unbounded, and you can explicitly set how to handle range bounds (to include them or not).

```
select *
from   test
where  daterange(start_date, end_date, '[]') &&
       daterange(date '2014-08-15', current_date, '[]');
```

Also, you can speed up this query, by applying a `gist` index on the `daterange` expression:

```
create index on test using gist ((daterange(start_date, end_date, '[]')));
```

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/56776/1)